# unable to set the exact css for login page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i want to create a login page like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/smEWd.jpg

but what i get is :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvpEL.jpg

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
// import { Button, FormGroup, input, label } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Login.css";

export default function Login1(props) {
//   const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
//   const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [user, setUser] = useState({email : "", password : ""})

  function validateForm() {
    return user.email.length > 0 && user.password.length > 0;
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
  }

  return (
    
    <div className="Login">
        <Header person = {user}/>
      <form className="modal-content animate" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div><h3 align='center'>Login</h3>
       </div>
       <div className="Container">
          
          <input type="text"
            autoFocus
            placeholder="Username"
            value={user.email}
            onChange={e => setUser({...user,email : e.target.value})}
          />
            {/* {console.log(user)} */}
        
          <br/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password"
            value={user.password} 
            onChange={e => setUser({...user,password : e.target.value})}
            
          />
        <br/><button disabled={!validateForm()}type="submit">
          Login
        </button> 
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        <button className="submit1" disabled="true" type="submit">
          Sign up
        </button>
        <br/><button className ="submit1" disabled="true" type="submit">
          Forgot Password?
        </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
  .Login {
    padding: 120px 0;
  }

  .Login form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
  }




  .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 80%; /* Full width */
    height: 80%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
  
  /* Modal Content/Box */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10px auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 120%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  }
  
  
  .footer {
    background-color: #9fa9a3;
    margin: 10px auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  }
  

  input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 30px;
  }
  
  /* Set a style for all buttons */
  button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  h3{
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  /* Add Zoom Animation */
   .animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.0s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.0s
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
  }
  
  @keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
  } */


  form {
    border: 3px solid #f0f0f0;
  }


}
```

I tried changing the width and CSS of the code. but still i couldn't get the exact login page design. could someone help me with this?

I have added the code snippet. I am doing this using react. I have done this html code in login.js and i have attached the CSS along with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `className` to Login button - **submit0**

```
<button className="submit0" disabled={!validateForm()} type="submit">
    Login
</button>
```

You've given `id` footer but you were using `.footer` in `.css` file, instead you've to use `#footer`.

Added css for background-image

```
.Login {
    background-image: url(https://i1.wp.com/512pixels.net/downloads/macos-wallpapers-thumbs/10-12--thumb.jpg?zoom=1.25&w=640);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 120px 0;
}
```

Opacity to Login Form

```
.Login form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Removed border from `.modal-content`

```
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10px auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    /* border: 1px solid #888; */
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 120%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

Footer css -

```
#footer {
/*background-color: #9fa9a3;
margin: 10px auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    /* border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 15px; */
    /*width: 100%;  Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    background-color: #666;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 11px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 11px;
}
```

For input field and login button, added left, right margin, border-radius and changed the width to 90%

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 8px 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 11px;
}
```

Buttons css -

```
.submit0 {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 8px 24px;
    border-radius: 11px;
}

.submit1 {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-shannon-uey2s)

Answer (score 0):

for testing is css file classes read correctly try put some custom inline styling in page and see this is work correctly if this work ok then you should check css class in main file and with inspect element check is Login.css loading on page

for inline styling : https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822